# How to have SharePoint 2010 Audit Reports show pages accessed WITH the parameters?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing

I managed to get a custom report from SharePoint showing me the activity of a particular list however it's important that I see which pages are being viewed and that would need the inclusion of ID parameters which are being dropped off on the audit report.

So what I'm getting is thistempplatedpage.aspx 5 times instead of

- thistempplatedpage.aspx?ID=15
- thistempplatedpage.aspx?ID=22
- thistempplatedpage.aspx?ID=15
- thistempplatedpage.aspx?ID=35
- thistempplatedpage.aspx?ID=11

All pages of course have different content and that is what needs to be tracked.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any of you super gurus out there know the answer?